# Get real value after create custom model attribute in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model

i was editing code from other programmer, and i found this code in model

```
public function getContentAttribute($value) {
    return (json_decode($value, true));
}
```

And how to get the real value when i call `$model->content` without removing the custom model attribute function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to define another accessor:

```
public function getContentOriginalAttribute($value) {
    return $this->attributes['content'];
}
```

Then accessing it this way:

```
$model->content_original
```